# Retrieve Info about ElasticSearch Nodes

Tags: node.js, api, elasticsearch, jsplumb, elasticsearch-marvel

I am Looking to Retrieve the Information Related to Nodes of Elastic Search running on a Machine. Info such as Master Node, CPU Utilization etc. and then Present that Info in a Graphical Manner on a Web Front using JSPlumb. I know that I have to use Elastic Search APIs like Nodes Info etc. But I don't know how to use APIs as such. Can anyone give me Headstart on this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats'
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/nodeId1,nodeId2/stats'
```

ref : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html